# Joining dataframe based on ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to left join one dataframe to another based on whether the values in the left data frame occur between a specified range indicated in the right dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['col1'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E']
df1['col2'] = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta','epsilon']
df1['min'] = [0, 15, 20, 90, 100]
df1['max'] = [15, 20, 90, 100, 200]

df2['x'] = np.linspace(0,199, 6)
```

My desired result is:

```
     x     col1    col2
0    0.0   'A'     'alpha'
1   39.8   'C'     'gamma'
2   79.6   'C'     'gamma'
3  119.4   'E'     'epsilon'
4  159.2   'E'     'epsilon'
5  199.0   'E'     'epsilon'
```

Does anyone know of a simple way to achieve this? Perhaps using the `merge`, `join` or `apply` methods?

### Edit

I have just edited my question to reflect more what is needed. I would like solutions which will not require me to explicitly type out every single non-range column in `df1` (i.e. `col1`, `col2` ... `coln`) as there will be too many columns to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another from [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) :

Note: `min` and `max` are methods (your df it is column names) so be careful if you use `.` (dot) notation.

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['min'],df1['max'], 'left')
df2 = df2.assign(**df1.set_index(s).loc[df2['x'],['col1','col2']].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or better is using `reindex` for missing values:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['min'],df1['max'], 'left')
df1.set_index(s).reindex(df2['x']).loc[:,['col1','col2']].reset_index()
```

---

```
print(df2)

       x col1     col2
0    0.0    A    alpha
1   39.8    C    gamma
2   79.6    C    gamma
3  119.4    E  epsilon
4  159.2    E  epsilon
5  199.0    E  epsilon
```

Comment: Sorry I just edited my question... I need solutions that don't explicitly require me to type out all the columns in `df1` that I need to bring over...

Comment: @user32882 Answer is edited to reflect the changes , basically you can pass a list of columns and assign back to df2

Comment: @user32882 added another method. :)

Comment: Please check the second edit to my question. Your solution seems to work but I am getting NAN values in the original problem as it excludes  the value 2 from the range...

Comment: @user32882 which case, sorry i didnt get you , can you change the example df to show this. thank you

Comment: actually you did. I'm playing around with the `closed` argument (trying `both`, `neither`, `left` and `right`) and it seems to be adjusting the interval types. Ideally I'd like to use `both` but it says it cannot reindex from an overlapping axis.... I mean intervals are intrinsic part of the problem right?

Comment: @user32882 seems like you have duplicate values?, I am on my way to work (if you can please update the question with a df usecase, i'll take a look once i reach :) )

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it solves the minimal working example I initially posted so it is a fair answer. However I made a new question to address the use of a non-positive range which seems to cause a problem....

Comment: The new question may be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676553/keyerror-for-joining-dataframe-based-on-ranges-including-negative-ranges

Comment: @user32882 sure, did you also try the reindex method?  (the second method I added) `df1.set_index(s).reindex(df2['x']).dropna(how='all')` ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the alternative solution posted in the new question... its a bit more intuitive IMO

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with bins and labels parameters from `df1` columns:

```
df2['new'] = pd.cut(df2['x'], bins=[df1['min'].iat[0]] + df1['max'].tolist(),
                    labels=df1['col1'],
                    include_lowest=True)
print (df2)
       x new
0    0.0   A
1   39.8   C
2   79.6   C
3  119.4   E
4  159.2   E
5  199.0   E
```

EDIT: For matching more columns change `df1` - last row and use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df1 = df1.append({'col1': df1['col1'].iat[-1], 'min': df1['max'].iat[-1]}, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.drop('max', 1).astype({'min':float})
print (df1)
  col1    min
0    A    0.0
1    B   15.0
2    C   20.0
3    D   90.0
4    E  100.0
5    E  200.0

df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, left_on='x', right_on='min')
print (df)
       x col1     col2    min
0    0.0    A    alpha    0.0
1   39.8    C    gamma   20.0
2   79.6    C    gamma   20.0
3  119.4    E  epsilon  100.0
4  159.2    E  epsilon  100.0
5  199.0    E  epsilon  100.0
```

Comment: will this scale if I have multiple columns like `'col1'`?