# KeyError for joining dataframe based on ranges (including negative ranges)

Tags: python, pandas

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666834/joining-dataframe-based-on-ranges/59667008?noredirect=1#comment105510642_59667008) I was able to join columns from one data frame to another based on whether the values occur in a specified range. The solution posted by @anky_91 worked for the limited working example I provided, however some simple changes are causing problems which indicate to me that the solution is not yet generic enough.

For instance, consider the use of ranges which go from a maximum value of 2 to a minimum value of -13. Aside from truncating `df1` to match with this, this is the only change from the previous question:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['col1'] = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df1['col2'] = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']

df1['max'] = [2, -3, -7]
df1['min']= [-3, -7, -13]

active_pressures = pd.DataFrame()
df2['x'] = np.linspace(2, -13, 100)


s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['min'],df1['max'], 'left')
df2 = df2.assign(**df1.set_index(s).loc[df2['x'],['col1','col2']].reset_index(drop=True))
```

The above throws a KeyError. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most general solution is cross join both DataFrames together and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df2.assign(a=1), on='a')
df1 = df[(df['x'] >= df['min']) & (df['x'] < df['max'])]
```

Also I think here is possible use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) like in previous answer if all data from `x` are between `min` and `max`.

> The above throws a KeyError. Why does that happen?

I guess bug, but not 100% sure. The best post new issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

Comment: How do I control whether the ranges are open or closed then?

Comment: @user32882 - You are right, then `df[(df['x'] >= df['min']) & (df['x'] < df['max'])]` is necessary.

Comment: I like this way better. It's more intuitive to me and allows me to control whether the boundaries are closed or not...